# Reading number of grades from text file

Tags: python, file

I'm trying to write a program that takes a list of grades from a .txt file, counts up the occurrences of that grade, and tells how many students received that grade.

The format of the list is one grade per line, so 6 `A`'s would return 6 students got `A`.

I managed to get the code to work, but it's running so many checks and I feel there's a way to reduce it, but I'm not sure how.

I think it might have something to do with lists or dictionaries.

```
def distribution(filename):
    'string ==> int & string, prints out how many students got a letter grade'
    infile = open(filename,'r')
    grades = infile.read()
    aCount = grades.count('A\n')
    aMinusCount = grades.count('A-\n')
    bCount = grades.count('B\n')
    bMinusCount = grades.count('B-\n')
    cCount = grades.count('C\n')
    cMinusCount = grades.count('C-\n')
    dCount = grades.count('D\n')
    dMinusCount = grades.count('D-\n')
    fCount = grades.count('F')
    print(aCount, 'students got A')
    print(aMinusCount, 'students got A-')
    print(bCount, 'students got B')
    print(bMinusCount, 'students got B-')
    print(cCount, 'students got C')
    print(cMinusCount, 'students got C-')
    if dCount == 0:
        pass
    else:
        print(dCount, 'students got D')
    if dMinusCount == 0:
        pass
    else:
        print(dMinusCount, 'students got D-')
    print(fCount, 'students got F')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could easily be done with a `collections.Counter` object:

```
import collections
infile = open(filename,'r')
grades = [g.strip() for g in infile.readlines()]
grade_counter = collections.Counter(grades)
for g, n in sorted(grade_counter.items()):
    print n, "students got", g
```

Comment: Okay, thank you! One more thing though. When I tested it out, it read the number of grades correctly, however at the end of the file are 2 F's. It only counts one F and the other goes into some kind of phantom grade "1 student got  ", but when I change the second F to F-, it says 2 students got F.

Comment: That's because there's no newline at the end of the file. You can either add a newline to the input file (which is actually always a good idea), or add it yourself when the file is read in. (Before doing the grade subsetting, say `if not g[-1].endswith("\n")` etc)

Comment: @iKyriaki: Better yet, see my edit, which uses `strip` to remove a newline whenever there is one.

Answer (score 1):

Using a [dictionary comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=dictionary%20comprehension#dictionaries):

```
def distribution(filename):
    'string ==> int & string, prints out how many students got a letter grade'
    infile = open(filename,'r')
    grades = infile.read().split('\n')
    # this creates a list of the grades, without the new-line character
    infile.close()
    possible_grades = ('A', 'A-', 'B', 'B-', 'C', 'C-', 'D', 'D-', 'F')
    gradesDict = {i:grades.count(i) for i in possible_grades}
    for x in gradesDict.keys():
        print(x + ':', gradesDict[x])
```